# How can I search informations from file with names using input (java)?

Tags: java, file, input

(I copy-pasted the whole code, but you just have to look at line 28 to 45)
We have to input the surname and the firstname to get the number of votes that the actual person got.
I wrote a code and if I type in the input the first row surname firstname it works nicely(I get 19, which on is the correct number), but every time when I try to write another name in the input field it doesn't work.

Inside the file there are 5 cloumns, (1st and the 5th is unnecessary in this problem)
2.cloumn we have votes that a person got
3.column we have surnames and obviously in the 4.cloumn we have first names.

[kepviselok.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7tdD.png)

[expected and actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ4kk.png)

```
    package erettsegi2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        var lista = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("kepviselok.txt"));
        var listak = new ArrayList<Lista>();
        var input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (var valaszt : lista) {
            String[] split = valaszt.split(" ");
            var kerSzam = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            var szavazottSzam = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            var nev = split[2] + " " + split[3];
            var part = split[4].equals("-") ? "Independent " : split[4];

            listak.add(new Lista(kerSzam, szavazottSzam, nev, part));
        }
        System.out.println("2.");
        System.out.println("Number of Representatives on Election: " + listak.size());

        System.out.println("3.\nPlease write a surname!");
        var surname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please write a first name!");
        var firstname = input.nextLine();

        for (var i = 0; i < listak.size();i++) {
            var actualCandidate = listak.get(i);

            if (actualCandidate.name.equals(surname + " " + firstname)) {
                System.out.println(actualCandidate.name);
                System.out.println("Number of votes " + actualCandidate.votes);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No candidate with this name");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    static class Lista {
        int sorszam;
        int votes;
        String name;
        String part;

        public Lista(int sorszam, int szavazatokSzama, String nev, String part) {
            this.sorszam = sorszam;
            this.votes = szavazatokSzama;
            this.name = nev;
            this.part = part;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question. So: no links of string data: just put up a nice "table" like section here in your question with actual vs expected output!

Comment: And just for the record: even when putting up code: when you use "non English" there, that reduces your chance of getting good answers.

Comment: I tried to edit my question. I hope now it's more readable than the previous.

Comment: You still have a _picture_ of your output instead of actual text included with your question. Also, I can't even _attempt_ to reproduce what you're doing with your code because you haven't included any example of what your input file `kepviselok.txt` looks like.  At this point I'm tempted to vote to close your question as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: I added a .txt file when I asked 1st, but @GhostCat told me to edit my code and change a picture to 'atcual vs expected output'. Now I will upload kepviselok.txt file  in the question, so you will able to look at that file.

Comment: As for basic debugging, if you print out the records in `listak`, what do you get? what is the size of `listak`?

Comment: The size of listak is 40. If I print out listak I get the content of the file.

Comment: The key thing to follow here is: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on your code, in the last cycle you have condition `if-else` and this condition will finish the cycle if first candidate name not equals (`else` executed, and you have `break` inside it) or this condition will finish the cycle because you found candidate in the first line (`if` block executed). It means that you are checking only first entry of your list, then cycle finishes because `if` or `else` block executed.

So, correct solution will be move print of `"No candidate with this name"` outside of cycle if you haven't found candidate (I added `boolean candidateFound` variable for this purpose), because only after check of whole list you can state that:

```
boolean candidateFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i < listak.size(); i++) {
    var actualCandidate = listak.get(i);

    if (actualCandidate.name.equals(surname + " " + firstname)) {
        System.out.println(actualCandidate.name);
        System.out.println("Number of votes " + actualCandidate.votes);

        candidateFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!candidateFound) {
    System.out.println("No candidate with this name");
}
```